# DocuSign INVALID_CONTENT_TYPE on creating envelope

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I am sending accesstoken along with document data but getting this error . Am I sending doc data in correct order

```
bodyData = {
  "status": "sent",
  "emailSubject": "Sent from the DocuSign REST API",
  "documents": [{
    "documentId": "1",
    "name": "contract.pdf",
    "documentBase64": "base64 document bytes...",
  }],
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [{
      "email": "....",
      "name": "Jane Dough",
      "recipientId": "....",
      "routingOrder": "1",
    }]
  }
}

curl.setHeaders([
  `Authorization: Bearer ${auth}`,
  "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
])
  .setBody(bodyData)
  .post(`https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/${accountId}/envelopes`)
  .then(({ statusCode, body, headers }) => {
    console.log('body : ', body)

    return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      data: body
    });
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
  });
    } catch (err) {
  console.log("err : ", err);
  // next(Boom.badImplementation(err));
}
```

Comment: can you try to change the Content-Type: application/json instead?

Comment: Also note that the 'created' status code that you'll receive is 201

Comment: @InbarGazit, please add your answer as an answer so it can be upvoted.  Thanks

Comment: Did try application/json. Now this error pops up :                                          
`body :  {"errorCode":"INVALID_REQUEST_BODY","message":"The request body is missing or improperly formatted. Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: s. Path '', line 0, position 0."}`                                                     I guess the error is because of bodyData. What should be the fields that i should use in bodyData?

Answer (score 0):

Need to change the content_type to application/json

Also, need to ensure proper body is sent in the request.

I would also recommend you consider using the latest version, 2.1 of our eSig REST API

See documentation of this API here - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/create

Comment: Yes I am using the documentation as a reference point. For the sake of it I am sending (Generic JSON Request/Response
Request from doc) . But still receiving error : invaild request body with message The request body is missing or improperly formatted. Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: d. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Comment: have you considered using one of our SDKs? that would help you avoid needing to format the specific json and the REST calls yourself.

Comment: Am I sending the correct format data```let pdfBase64 = await pdf2base64("http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf");
  let bodyData = {
   "status": "sent",
   "emailSubject": "Sent from the DocuSign REST API",
   "documents": [{
    "documentId": "1",
    "name": "sample.pdf",
    "documentBase64": pdfBase64,
   }],
   "recipients": {
    "signers": [{
     "email": "nkt.jsh17@gmail.com",
     "name": "AnkitJoshi",
     "recipientId": "1",
     "routingOrder": "1",
    }]
   }
  };```

Comment: pdfBase64 is what? you assign to it but you also use it inside for the value of the document? that's your issue. Can you hardcode this as a string to test first? before you do the real thing

Comment: pdfBase64 is the pdf in base64 format (as described in doc). ```pdfBase64 = await pdf2base64("http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf");```

Comment: your json is bad, I would recommend using an SDK. If not - please provide the exact json that was sent to API so we can see what's wrong